# How to pair Android Tablet with Samsung Watch 4

Tags: samsung, tablet, lenovo, smartwatch

It seems that Samsung Watch 4 cannot be paired to tablet for some reason even tough you can install Samsung Wear app on the tablet and pair the watch via Bluetooth (so the tablet can see the watch). Just the Samsung Wear app does not see the watch.

Tried googling for a long time but outside of "it is not officially supported" nothing helpful. How to make this work? Ideally without rooting anything.